# MySQL - Improving performance of a slow subquery

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have a large database of horse racing results. A normal query is very fast to run, however when using a subquery, performance is incredibly slow to the point it's not viable.

The purpose of the subquery is to determine the results of a given horse, prior to the date of the race. Hence the where clause.

I would like to improve performance and as I understand it using a join is much faster, however I haven't been able to get it to work successfully.

I would love to know how to join this particular query?

I apologize for not adding a SQL Fiddle, however the sheer size of the data required, even for a sample, is just too large.

```
select date, raceref, horse, rank, 

 (
SELECT ifnull(count(raceref),0)
FROM results
WHERE horse = t.horse
  AND date < t.date
   ) AS totalracesprior,

FROM results t
group by horse, raceref
order by raceref, horse
```

The output from EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY t   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    110088  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  results ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    110088  Using where
```

Indexes:

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
results 0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   110088  NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

Comment: You don't need to add an sql fiddle, but you should add your indexes (the output of `Show indexes from results` and explain (output of `explain` directly infront of your query). And you can remove the `order by date desc limit 1`, is has no purpose here.

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare, I'll make those updates.

Comment: You absolutely need at least an index `results(horse)`. You may get better results with an index `results(horse, date, raceref)`, that depends a little on your data.

Comment: That's done the trick @Solarflare. If you want to add that as the answer please do and I can mark it answered.

Comment: Thanks for showing timely updates to your question to @Solarflare . It's awesome when people do that to get answers versus just ignoring the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely need an index for the column `horse`.

You can either use the index `results(horse)` or the index `results(horse, date, raceref)`. The latter would provide full coverage of your subquery and probably yield better results, but it depends a little bit on your data if you would see a difference.

Comment: It is unclear what `raceref` is.  The only difference between `COUNT(raceref)` and `COUNT(*)` is that the former checks `raceref` for NULL.  So, switch to the latter and go with simply `INDEX(horse, date)`.

Answer (score 1):

Are there multiple rows with the *same* combination of `horse, raceref`?  If so, the `GROUP BY horse, raceref` will not work as intended.

If there are not dups, then get rid of the `GROUP BY`; it adds work without changing the results.

I recommend two indexes: `INDEX(horse, date)` is useful for the subquery.  Without the `GROUP BY`, `INDEX(raceref, horse)` is useful for the `ORDER BY`.  It would be useful also for the `GROUP BY` if you swapped the order there.